# How could I split a string between two specific characters?

Tags: c

I have a string (file name) and I would like to extract a string between to characters, for example:

```
string="/export/aibn84_2/SED/Sbc_cww.sed"
```

I need to store the string between last `"/"` and `"_cww.sed"` ,which would be `"sbc"`, in an array to use it later. 
Could anybody give me some tips?

P.S. If I want to read a list of files and separate this part of their names and then define  a string array and save them in the array's elements, how should I apply it?

Comment: Will the characters before `Sbc_cww.sed` always be constant?

Comment: 1) look for the last '/' 2) look for "_cww.sed" after that. 3) use the characters between 1 and 2 as a source for copying the wanted string.

Comment: Take a look at the strtok function.

Comment: is the underlinr position clear for you?

Comment: @Sevauk: Bad advice IMO (strtok is ugly and needs to modify the source string). Better would be strchr() or strrchr() plus strstr() or memmem() (which is a gnu-extension)

Comment: BTW what should the program do when the input is `string="/export/aibn84_2/SED/Sbc_cww.sedative"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two functions that come in use:

`strrchr` -> Locate last occurrence of character in string

`strncpy` -> Copy the first *num* characters from string

`strstr`  -> Returns a pointer to the first occurrence of str2 in str1

```
char str[] = "/export/aibn84_2/SED/Sbc_cww.sed";
char* pch;
pch=strrchr(str,'/');
char* pch2;
pch2=strstr(str,"_cww.sed");
char value[40];
strncpy(value, pch+1, pch2-(pch+1));
printf("%s\n", value);
```

Comment: That's good, but I think he will need to use `strstr(str,"_cww.sed") because the `_` may be present somewhere else as well

Comment: The strncpy() is wrong (it assumes value[] to be initialized with zeros (which it is not) and/or "_cww.sed" to be followed by a NUL character (which is not necessarily so) There is also no check for pch1 and pch2 being NULL (or pch2 < pch1) which is **very** wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
    char str[] = "/export/aibn84_2/SED/Sbc_cww.sed"; // define the full array
    char *str_start = strrchr(str, '/')+1; // locat the first character after the last '/'
    char *str_end = strstr(str_start, "_cww.sed"); // locat "_cww.sed" after the last '/'
    char str_new[str_end-str_start+1]; // define the new array
    strncpy(str_new, str_start, str_end-str_start); // copy the elements bitween the start and the and
    str_new[str_end-str_start] = '\0'; // terminate the new array with the null character
    puts(str_new); // print the new array
    return 0;
}
```